# Is it possible to use Elixir changesets/validations without using models?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Would this be as simple as defining your schema and `def changeset` and never writing any `Repo.insert(changeset)`?

Comment: By "without using models" you mean without using a database table for that schema?

Comment: That's correct - without needing to insert any data into a database but rather just to validate data

Answer (score 5):

It is possible and I find it as perfect way to validate API requests.

You can define your model without backend as:

```
defmodule MyApp.Models.File do
  schema "" do
    field :description, :string, virtual: true
    field :url,         :string, virtual: true
    field :file_name,   :string, virtual: true
    field :ext,         :string, virtual: true
    field :mime,        :string, virtual: true
    field :size,        :integer, virtual: true
  end

  def new_file_cs(model, params) do
    model
    |> cast(params, ~w(url file_name ext mime size), ~w(description))
  end
end
```

and then somewhere call it as:

```
def handle_request(data) do
  changeset = File.new_file_cs(%File{}, data)
  case changeset.valid? do
    true  -> :ok
    false -> {:error, changeset}
  end
end
```

Such error response can be used with ChangesetView generated by phoenix to return uniform error response.

To summarize, your model should have empty schema "" and all fields should be virtual: true

Answer (score 2):

There's an `Ecto.Changeset` like validation library called `Justify`. It allows you to validate against plain maps and structs. No schemas or types necessary.

https://github.com/sticksnleaves/justify

You can do stuff like:

```
import Justify

dataset =
  %{email: "anthony@someemail.com"}
  |> validate_required(:email)
  |> validate_format(:email, ~r/\A\S@\S\z/)

dataset.valid? == true
```

Disclaimer: I made `Justify`

Answer (score 2):

Ecto has `embedded_schema` which allows you to define a schema and use changesets without defining a source. See [here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Schema.html#embedded_schema/1) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't looked at later docs:
You can use changesets without defining schemas https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/2.1.0-rc.4/Ecto.Changeset.html#module-schemaless-changesets